# Expectation Of Binomial R.V.

Tags: probability

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoxsJ.jpg
I don't understand how it goes from the first equality to the second equality I understand that Y is a binomial random variable with parameters n-1 and p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $Y\sim\mathrm{bin}(n-1,p)$ then
$$
{\rm E}[g(Y)]=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} g(j)P(Y=j)
$$
for any nice function $g$ by the [law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

Comment: Wow that makes sense. Thanks. Wish they would point it out in the textbook.